# Traverse complex object using Optional stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I want to iterate a list with nested list of object similar to below

```
Country {
  String name;
  State capital
  List<State> states;
}

State {
  String name;
  City capital
  List<City> cities;
}

City {
  String name;
}
```

I am using below code to get the capital list of all states with name 'XYZ'

```
List<Country> countries = getCountriesList();

if (countries != null) {
    countries.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(country -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(country.getStates()))
            .flatMap(country -> country.getStates().stream())
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(state -> "XYZ".equalsIgnoreCase(state.getName()))
            .map(State::getCapital)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(capital -> capital.getName())
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

How can I refactor this to avoid using non null at each step?

Comment: What's wrong with using `nonNull`? Your code looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to avoid using `nonNull`. The current way of doing it is perfectly readable, and it clearly shows your intentions. If I really were to nitpick, I would remove the filter for empty states,

```
.filter(country -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(country.getStates()))
```

since this is already covered by the `flatMap` in the next line. Also, you can use `.toList()` instead of `collect` since Java 9.

That said, if you really want to get rid of the `nonNull` filters, you can do so by using a lot of `Optional`s. The capital and capital name null checks can be done by flat mapping to the optional's `stream`, and the state null check can be combined with the `"XYZ"` state name filter on the next line.

That gives us:

```
countries.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(country -> country.getStates().stream())
    .filter(state -> state != null && "XYZ".equalsIgnoreCase(state.getName()))
    .flatMap(state -> Optional.ofNullable(state.getCapital()).stream())
    .flatMap(capital -> Optional.ofNullable(capital.getName()).stream())
    .toList();
```

The first null check is a bit hard to get rid of, unless you have a known country that has no states:

```
public static final Country EMPTY = new Country("", null, List.of());
```

Then you could use `Objects.requireNonNullElse` to default to the `EMPTY` country:

```
countries.stream()
    .flatMap(country -> Objects.requireNonNullElse(country, Country.EMPTY).getStates().stream())
```

Really though, with each `nonNull` you avoid, you are just making the code harder to read.

Comment: Instead of `Optional.ofNullable(…).stream()` you can use `Stream.ofNullable(state.getCapital())` in the first place. And I fully agree with the nitpick. Not only is testing for an empty collection before `flatMap` pointless, using an obscure 3rd party library utility method instead of the built-in `isEmpty()` method (i.e. `country -> ! country.getStates() .isEmpty()`) is even worse. By the way, you could also combine `.filter(Objects::nonNull) .flatMap(country -> country.getStates().stream())` to a single operation, `.flatMap(country -> country == null? null: country.getStates().stream())`

Comment: Or `.flatMap(country -> country == null? Stream.empty(): country.getStates() .stream())` as people might prefer `Stream.empty()` over `null` for stylistic reasons even if the contract of `flatMap` states that `null` is treated like an empty stream…

Comment: here CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty() is checking that the collection country.getStates() is not null and not empty so that country.getStates().stream() doesn't throw a null pointer exception, but yeah we can replace it with the built-in method.

Comment: @Jayadeep Ah so `getStates` could also return null. The first `flatMap` would need to return `Objects.requireNonNullElse(country.getStates(), List.of()).stream()`  to handle that.